# acmart: problem with \protect

Tags: sectioning, acm

I'm using the recent [acmart](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acmart?lang=en) package and would like to put math characters into several section headings. I know there are issues relating to "fragile" and the interaction with `hyperref` (which `acmart` uses) which I don't understand well; however the usual `\protect` incantation does not work. The following fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\newcommand*{\verifiedBy}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\models$}}}

\begin{document}
$\verifiedBy$ % ok
\section{$\protect\verifiedBy$} % borks
\end{document}
```

The message I get is:

```
! Argument of \GPT@temp has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 \section{$\protect\verifiedBy$}
```

If I replace `acmart` by `article`, and import `graphicx` for `\reflectbox`, everything is fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\newcommand*{\verifiedBy}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\models$}}}

\begin{document}
$\verifiedBy$ % ok
\section{$\protect\verifiedBy$} % also ok
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `hyperref` has no idea how to handle the `\reflectbox`. In such cases one should use

```
\texorpdfstring{TeX stuff}{pdf stuff}
```

The first argument is what will be typeset by `TeX` and the second one enters the information of the pdf file. The sectioning command should be

```
\section{Section with \texorpdfstring{$\protect\verifiedBy$}{symbol}}
```

In this case the printed section title will be what you expect, and the navigation panel of the pdf reader will contain "Section with symbol".

**EDIT**: As per egreg's suggestion, this solution is easy if you need it only once; if the symbol will likely occur many times in moving arguments it may be better to use

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\verifiedBy{replacement symbol}}
```

---

Your definition of `\verifiedBy` is by the way much more complicated than necessary. A look into the `LaTeX` sources shows that `\models` is defined by

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\models}{\mathrel{|}\joinrel\Relbar}
```

where `\Relbar` is essentially `\mathrel{=}` (but also robust), and `\joinrel` is a negative space. Without reflecting boxes you can just define

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\verifiedBy}{\Relbar\joinrel\mathrel{|}}
```

Declaring the command as robust allows to omit the `\protect` in the argument of the sectioning command.

Comment: Something like `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\verifiedBy{VB}}` would avoid the need for `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: @egreg Yep, forgot about that, thanks for the suggestion. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great, thanks. I did experiment with `\texofpdfstring` but I don't think I tried the two together. Re. `\verifiedBy`, I guess I generally avoid "breaking the abstraction" and depending on how something is implemented, but I agree that in this case it probably makes sense.